# Removing a jar in sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have this in my gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}
```

When I print the `runtimeClasspath` in this code:

```
task runTopology(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.each { println it }
```

I get something like:

```
...
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.lmax/disruptor/3.3.2/8db3df28d7e4ad2526be59b54a1cbd9c9e982a7a/disruptor-3.3.2.jar
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.1/588c32c91544d80cc706447aa2b8037230114931/log4j-api-2.1.jar
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.1/31823dcde108f2ea4a5801d1acc77869d7696533/log4j-core-2.1.jar
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.1/fe9d0925aeee68b743e9ea4b68ca9190a2a411a/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.6/170e8f7395753ebbe6710bb862a84689db1f128b/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
...
```

Is it possible to exclude the line below in `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`?

```
/home/steven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.1/fe9d0925aeee68b743e9ea4b68ca9190a2a411a/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar
```

I do not want to include it in the `runtimeClasspath` as it crashes with another class in the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FileCollection.filter()](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) to filter by file name.
The following will exclude `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar` from `runtimeClasspath` :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath = runtimeClasspath.filter { File file ->
            file.name ==~ "log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar" ? null : file
        }
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
        runtimeClasspath = runtimeClasspath.filter { File file ->
            file.name ==~ "log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar" ? null : file
        }
    }
}
```