# Gradle 7.0 migration: how to remove a JAR from compileClasspath

Tags: java, gradle

We were previously using this snippet in our `build.gradle.kts` file to remove a dependency that was added to the `compileClasspath` by another plugin:

```kotlin
project.afterEvaluate {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            compileClasspath -= files(the_jar_to_remove)
        }
    }
}
```

We are now trying to migrate from Gradle 6.8 to 7.2 and this seems to have no effect anymore. When the `javaCompile` task runs, I can see that the JAR is still there in the classpath (using `--debug`).

Is there any way to achieve the same thing with Gradle 7.0?

FYI, this "trick" was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512061/removing-a-jar-in-sourcesets-main-runtimeclasspath) and [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/310).